# android url always return empty string

Tags: android

so here is my code, and i've tried the getContent on the basic java and it works fine. but here it doesn't at all. the content of the url i load is always empty. i've also added the permission.INTERNET to the manifest. i'm new to android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String lines="";
    try {
        lines=getContent("http://detik.com");
    }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(lines);

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You clicked yes button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public static String getContent(String url) {
    String pageContent="";
    try
    {
        URL pageLink=new URL(url);
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pageLink.openStream()));

        String line=in.readLine();
        while (line!=null)
        {
            pageContent=pageContent+line;
            line=in.readLine();
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return "content of "+url+" : "+pageContent;
}
```

and this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.myuser.testtabview" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: u can not directly load url in Main thread android activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the function below:

```
public void getContent(String url) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                HttpURLConnection conn = null;

                try {
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json,text/html");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "");

                    try {
                        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                                "UTF-8"));
                        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line).append("\n");
                        }
                        br.close();
                        is.close();
                        conn.disconnect();
                        return sb.toString();

                    } catch (SocketException e) {// connection reset
                        Log.d(TAG, "SocketException: " + e);
                        return null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {// connection reset
                        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);

                // You get the result here

            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

Http connection is considered as time consuming action, so you need put it into another thread instead of the UI thread, so in the sample I used a AsyncTask, the result will be in the onPostExcecute function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do "internet work" on the main thread, you have to use AsyncTask like that example.

```
private class AsyncTaskDownloadSomething extends 
        AsyncTask<String[], String, String> {

    DataClassLentABook  mData;





    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        super.onPreExecute(); 
        //Do some prepartations over here, before the task starts to execute 
        //Like freeze the button and/or show a progress bar 


    } 





    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Task starts executing. 
        String url = urls[0];

        // Execute HTTP requests here, with one url(urls[0]), 
        // or many urls using the urls table 
        // Save result in myresult 

        return myresult; 

    } 





    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               //Do modifications you want after everything is finished 
               //Like re-enable the button, and/or hide a progressbar 
               //And of course do what you want with your result got from http-req 



    } 
}
```

To execute your async task, when your button is clicked, just write this:

```
new AsyncTaskDownloadSomething().execute(someURL);
```

Comment: i've been trying to but it said that i need at least 15 reputation, i'll get back to vote your answer as soon as i've reached enough reputation